# How to create new localhost interface in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ifconfig, netsh, network-interface

In *unix you can write:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 127.0.2.1 up
```

But how to do this command line in Windows?

Comment: [NETSH (Network Shell)](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)

Comment: Please give me more specific example? For the aforenamed command using netsh

Comment: I don't know how `ifconfig` works. I do know that `netsh` is the closest windows equivalent. Please read the link. There are examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: this is defined in the hosts file under Windows: "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\HOSTS": **127.0.0.1 localhost**

Comment: So just to add this in the file?

Comment: this should be already included. Check the file.